# A problem with limit

Tags: calculus, limits

How to attack this one?

Does the following limit exists:

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\dfrac {\cos^5x\sin^5x} {x^8\sin^2x-2x^7\sin x\cos^2x+x^6\cos^4x+x^2\cos^8x}$$

Comment: Before embarking, I would suggest to cheat and [check this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gvawe4s6v1).

Comment: Can you explain me what does this graph shows, it sure isn´t the graph of this function, if you meant that?

Comment: Why? I think I carefully pasted the expression of your function in the left hand side box... So if I did not make a typo and if desmos does its job, it seems to prove that the limits at $\pm\infty$ and $0$ are $0$. Why not?

Comment: Then you discovered an error in Desmos beacuse the situation is quite more serious as Wolfram Alpha shows:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28cos%5E5x+sin%5E5x%29%2F%28x%5E8sin%5E2x-2x%5E7sinxcos%5E2x%2Bx%5E6cos%5E4x%2Bx%5E2cos%5E8x%29

Comment: Interesting. At least they agree on the behaviour at $\pm\infty$ which is what you want. I'll remember not to trust desmos too much.

Comment: I will understand this as a joke, how do you know that this function doesn`t oscillate again at $\pm 10^{1000000}$, for example?

Comment: I'm not saying it's a proof...I'm not in secondary school. I'm saying it makes it plausible that the limit is $0$...

Comment: Okay, I am sorry if you understood my comment as an insult on you, I am of the opinion that the limit doesn`t exist.

Comment: It depends if the angle is expressed in radian or degree. If the angle is in radian the limit is zero. **Note** wolframalpha considers x in degree

Comment: That simply is not true. It cannot depend on that.

Comment: No problem. But you have a fairly rough way to welcome people's comments. With me, like with @Abhijit. And if you understood the whole thing that well, you should answer your question.

Comment: julien, I said I am sorry and I felt that and I meant that, can we be non-hostile now?

antonio, I think that both approaches are okay, it depends on how much you "zoom the graph" as I can see now from your helpful reaction, thank you.

Comment: What would happen if you divide every term by x^8 and go from there? If you take the limit to infinity, what will happen with all the terms that will have an x in the denominator? Yes, they diminish. There is then that very interesting quadratic sine term that messes things up in order for this limit to exist, in my opinion After all, how many times does this sine term become zero when x goes to infinity? But it doesn't stay zero all the time eventhough the numerator will then approach to zero. Now here is an issue :)
I (still) have no definite answer, but getting curious now...

Comment: The problem is that if you divide with $x^8$ it could be the case that $sin^2x-{\dfrac {sinxcos^2x}{x}}+{\dfrac {cos^4x}{x^2}+{\dfrac {cos^8x}{x^6}}}$ have an infinity of zeros in the $(0,+\infty)$ and if that is really the case I have no slightest idea how to prove it.

Comment: and julien, I would like that you help me in the future with my questions and with this one also if you find an idea on how to attack it.

Comment: Yes, I did not realize that. I just assumed these "rest" terms to become zero for x→infinity and I continued to work with the numerator and sin²x in the denom. In that way, using L'Hospital, it would become zero, but this approach (taking a limit on half the stuff) is not at all "clean", if not incorrect.

Comment: It could be incorrect, as far as I can see now, in order to solve this, one must be very precise, unless there is a trick of some kind?

Comment: Perhaps an extremely accurate graphing calculator could give some support as to establish if this limit exists or not. The graph may give an idea what would happen for very large values of x. Perhaps (and that is just a conjecture), the graph will approach zero, but for a certain set of values, for example every 2pi (I am making this up) it may jump away from it (asymptotic behavior) and then resume going to zero.

Comment: have you tried using the power numerator and denominator out. Then you should see that the limit is zero (I didn't check the signs)

Comment: I thought about that too. Powerseries work really well in case x approaches a particular value, but here x goes to infinity, so you cannot just consider only the first few terms (like we would otherwise often do) of a powerseries, and discard the Rest. Getting powersies of a trig term raised to a fairly high power seems cumbersome to me...

Comment: you're totally right, didn't thought of that. So another shot would be to replace $x$ with $1/x$ so that the limit is in fact a limit $x\to 0$. Maybe then this might work. Not sure if this really does. L'Hopital's rule also seem to be messy here. What about exploiting $\sin^2 +\cos^2 =1$ maybe several times?

Comment: I will look into that idea Quickbeam. I got to go now, so will check this again tomorrow...

Comment: The limit should be zero. The sign of $[x^6\sin x -2 x^5 \cos^2 x]$ is for large $x$ only determined by the first term that contains the $\sin$ function. However since one need to multiply it again by $\sin$ it's always non-negative. It can be zero but than the remaining terms in the denominator are non-zero. Hence one should be able to show that the denominator is for bounded below $x^2 C$ for some $C$ large. Since the numerator is bounded by $1$. we can estimate by $0\leq \text{expression} \leq C/x^2\to 0$ for large $x$. But the details could be technical

Comment: The problem is that it could be the case that the denominator have an infinity of zeroes, then the function would have an infinity of singularities.

Comment: yeah i was wrong, $[x^6\sinx−2x^5\cos^2 x]$ can be negative even if $\sin x$ is positive. But maybe one can show, that the other terms are in that cases large enough to conclude an estimate as above. Maybe it is imporant that all powers add up to ten.

Comment: Again, no problem! Take care.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The denominator can be rewritten as the sum of the two nonnegative terms
$$
(x \sin x - \cos^2 x)^2 x^6 + x^2 \cos^8 x.
$$
For all integral $n\ge 1$, when $x$ is in the interval $[2\pi n-\frac{\pi}{4}, 2\pi n+\frac{\pi}{4}]$ or $[2\pi n+\frac{3\pi}{4}, 2\pi n+\frac{5\pi}{4}]$, $|\cos x|\ge 2^{-1/2}$, so the second term will be at least $x^2/16$.  On the other hand, if $x$ is in the interval $[2\pi n+\frac{\pi}{4}, 2\pi n+\frac{3\pi}{4}]$ or $[2\pi n+\frac{5\pi}{4}, 2\pi n+\frac{7\pi}{4}]$, $|x \sin x|\ge  |\sin x|\ge 2^{-1/2}$ and $|\cos^2 x|\le\frac 12$, so the first term will be at least $\frac 12 x^6 (1-2^{-1/2})^2$.  Assume that $x\ge 2\pi$.  Then $\frac 12 x^6 (1-2^{-1/2})^2\ge x^2/16$, so, regardless of the interval $x$ belongs to, the denominator is bounded below by $x^2/16$.  Therefore, the limit exists and is zero.

Comment: Nicely done, +1.

Comment: You practically showed that there exists an uncountable set of sequences $x_n$ such that $lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=0$. But that doesn`t exclude the case that it could be the case that there exist sequence $a_n$ such that $a_{2n-1}\in [2\pi n-\frac{\pi}{4}, 2\pi n+\frac{\pi}{4}]$ or $a_{2n-1}\in [2\pi n+\frac{3\pi}{4}, 2\pi n+\frac{5\pi}{4}]$ and $a_{2n}\in [2\pi n+\frac{\pi}{4}, 2\pi n+\frac{3\pi}{4}]$ or $a_{2n}\in [2\pi n+\frac{5\pi}{4}, 2\pi n+\frac{7\pi}{4}]$ and $lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\neq0$.

Comment: The problem is in that, that your sequences tend to $\infty$ in a special fashion because $(2\pi n-\frac{\pi}{4}, 2\pi n+\frac{\pi}{4})$, $(2\pi n+\frac{3\pi}{4}, 2\pi n+\frac{5\pi}{4})$, $(2\pi n+\frac{\pi}{4}, 2\pi n+\frac{3\pi}{4})$,$(2\pi n+\frac{5\pi}{4}, 2\pi n+\frac{7\pi}{4})$ are mutually disjoint.

Comment: So we still do not have the proof.

Comment: In the first comment, i had a typo, change $lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\neq0$ to $lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)\neq0$.

Comment: Ok, I am going to ask a dumb question here perhaps, but if the denom can be written as the sum of two non negative squares, then the denom can not become negative, but perhaps zero. That would be the case if both terms are zero for the same x. The cos term is zero for pi multiples on pi/2 and for those values the other term can't be zero. So the denom will be positive for large x, or I am going off a cliff here?

Comment: By the way, that factorization by David is brilliant, irrespective of the problem!!

Comment: This is not the proof, if you don`t believe me then check carefully the arguments of David and characterization of continuity by Heine, which is equivalent to the standard Cauchy definition, and then modify Heine characterization of continuity to get Heine characterization of existence of a limit.

Comment: The proof is fine, I misunderstood something.